# Why is my asynchronous code with .NET Core 6 and SSH.NET working synchronously?

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, ssh.net

I need expand this code and will be call this code from Quartz thread and than notify frontend by SignalR, because operation will be going by hours.

But as first step I call this code directly from ASP.NET Core thread

```vb
Public Function AsyncBash(Model As KvmBashRequest) As IActionResult
                Return Ok(Server.BashAsync(Model.BashCmd))
....
Public Async Function BashAsync(BashCmd As String) As Task(Of String)
        Dim CTX = New Threading.CancellationToken()
        If SshClient.IsConnected Then
            Try
                Dim Cmd1 = SshClient.CreateCommand(BashCmd)
                Await Cmd1.ExecuteAsync(New Progress(Of SshOutputLine), CTX)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ex.Message
            End Try
        Else
            Return "not connected"
        End If
    End Function
.....
Public Class SshOutputLine
    Public Sub New(ByVal Line As String, ByVal IsErrorLine As Boolean)
        Debug.WriteLine($"{IsErrorLine}:{Line}")
    End Sub
End Class
.....
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Threading
Imports Renci.SshNet

Module SshCommandExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Async Function ExecuteAsync(ByVal SshCommand As SshCommand, ByVal OutputLine As IProgress(Of SshOutputLine), ByVal CTX As CancellationToken) As Task
        Dim AsyncResult = SshCommand.BeginExecute()
        Dim StdoutSR = New StreamReader(SshCommand.OutputStream)
        Dim StderrSR = New StreamReader(SshCommand.ExtendedOutputStream)
        While Not AsyncResult.IsCompleted
            Await Progress(SshCommand, StdoutSR, StderrSR, OutputLine, CTX)
            Thread.Yield()
        End While
        SshCommand.EndExecute(AsyncResult)
        Await Progress(SshCommand, StdoutSR, StderrSR, OutputLine, CTX)
   End Function

   Private Async Function Progress(ByVal SshCommand As SshCommand, ByVal StdoutSR As TextReader, ByVal StderrSR As TextReader, ByVal OutputLine As IProgress(Of SshOutputLine), ByVal CTX As CancellationToken) As Task
        If CTX.IsCancellationRequested Then SshCommand.CancelAsync()
        CTX.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        Await OutProgress(StdoutSR, OutputLine)
        Await ErrProgress(StderrSR, OutputLine)
   End Function

   Private Async Function OutProgress(ByVal StdoutSR As TextReader, ByVal StdoutProgress As IProgress(Of SshOutputLine)) As Task
        Dim StdoutLine = Await StdoutSR.ReadToEndAsync()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(StdoutLine) Then StdoutProgress.Report(New SshOutputLine(Line:=StdoutLine, IsErrorLine:=False))
   End Function

   Private Async Function ErrProgress(ByVal StderrSR As TextReader, ByVal stderrProgress As IProgress(Of SshOutputLine)) As Task
        Dim StderrLine = Await StderrSR.ReadToEndAsync()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(StderrLine) Then stderrProgress.Report(New SshOutputLine(Line:=StderrLine, IsErrorLine:=True))
   End Function
End Module
```

Unfortunately, this code is working fully synchronously, I expect a serious of call my class `SshOutputLine`, but I get it only once.

[image: SSH result]

This is thread tree of my Web API:

[image: Threading]

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score -1):

After thinking I have understanding issue, maybe call Async function is wrong. Correct way with `Task.Run` (wrong line commented)

```vb
Public Overloads Async Function Bash(BashCmd As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim CTX = New Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
    If SshClient.IsConnected Then
        Try
            Dim Cmd1 = SshClient.CreateCommand(BashCmd)
            Await Task.Run(Function() Cmd1.ExecuteAsync(New Progress(Of SshOutputLine), CTX.Token, SshOutput, SshErrMsg))
            'Await Cmd1.ExecuteAsync(New Progress(Of SshOutputLine), CTX)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    Else
        Await Task.Run(Function() "not connected")
    End If
End Function
```

Second issue - need to really huge output like `ls -R -la /` to test this future. For huge Linux server with 21 millions of output chars buffer was fill and flush only for times.

[Huge output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4yIZ.png)
[Buffer size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u53kS.png)

NewLine is ready exactly in Thread.Yield.

[image: Thread.Yield]

I can not publish full code, sorry, because my code little bit hard to understanding for C# programmers, because I use Shadow and other strong OOP concepts beyond understanding of C# programmers.

[OOP wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4m8a.png)